# How do I add an RSS feed to PyroCMS?

Tags: pyrocms

I am trying to add an RSS feed to a website through PyroCMS (Version 2.1.4). I want it to be a feed of all of the blog posts in our PyroCMS.

I don't want to display RSS items from another site. I want to syndicate out OUR items.

Comment: Are you talking about the rss feeds at the admin dashboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyroCMS has an RSS feed in the blog module, which can be found here.

> http://www.yoursite.com/blog/rss

From here: http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/modules/blog#blog-rss-feed

Comment: Yep, thats how it works. If you're using FireFox you can just click the RSS icon in the address bar.